# Git update on local file change

Tags: git

Situation:

I want to save my development environment settings on github

For example my .profile settings file.

So i created one git repository online where i store various settings like

.profile
My packages installed etc

Now i clone this online repository to solve local path say

/home/code/github_settings

This on-line project has latest .profile file. Now if i change the local .profile in /home/user/.profile , i want to automatically update 
/home/code/github_settings/.profile

So that any change in local .profile is copied to github project and i can commit back online.

Comment: How about using symlinks? (`~/.foo` as a symlink to `~/my_git_repo/.foo`).

Comment: Thanks , for files i can use this. What about folders

Comment: Symlinks work for both.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of repository is often called [dotfiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=dotfiles&oq=dotfiles&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3312j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). As you can see from that Google search, there are many developers doing similar things as you. I suggest you look at how they set things up in their repos to get ideas of how to solve the problems you are facing.

I believe that one solution is to include a shell script in your dotfiles repo which creates symlinks in your home directory to each of the files in your repo.